# Java, Vaadin 8, lazy loading with grid

Tags: java, vaadin-grid, vaadin8

I am trying to implement lazy loading with Grid in Vaadin 8. But it only shows an empty table. What do I do wrong? Also, how do I set the number of items to load (limit) to for example 20 items (the default is 40 items)?

```
private Grid<Image> makeLazyTable()
{
  Grid<Image> grid = new Grid<Image>();     
  DataProvider<Image, Void> dataProvider = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
    query -> {
      int offset = query.getOffset();
      int limit = query.getLimit();        
      OffsetRequest request = new OffsetRequest();
      request.setLimit(limit);
      request.setOffset(offset);  
      List<QuerySortOrder> sort = query.getSortOrders();
      return ImagesRepository.findAll(request, sort);
    },
    query -> ImagesRepository.getImageCount()
  );    
  grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);     
  return grid;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your count and fetch code? What count is returned, does the findAll return Image objects?

Comment: Yes, I debugged the count and fetch code. Image objects are returned by the fetch code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not add any columns. That was the reason why the table was empty.
This way it works:

```
Column<Image, String> filenameColumn = grid.addColumn(Image::getFilename);
Column<Image, String> orientationColumn = grid.addColumn(Image::getOrientation);
Column<Image, String> latitudeColumn = grid.addColumn(Image::getLatitude);
Column<Image, String> longitudeColumn = grid.addColumn(Image::getLongitude);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. For the record, you can let the `Grid` class automatically create the columns if you pass the bean type to the constructor: `Grid<Image> grid = new Grid<>(Image.class)`.