# How to show Database TABLE at Vaadin8 website?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mybatis, vaadin8

Im doing a simple website using Spring Tool Suite, Maven, Vaadin8.
I have database in postgreSQL.
I know how to connect it all together, but problem is how to show it in Vaadin8?
I found some tutorial but it's for Vaadin7.
https://vaadin.com/blog/building-a-web-ui-for-postgresql-databases
Connecting database is simple, but problem begins when I want to show it.

```
new BeanItemContainer<>(Company.class, companies));
setFormVisible(false);
```

It doesn't work anymore with Vaadin8, and there is no tutorial about displaying tables from database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to a database configured and you are able to get items from it, there are two options.

1. If you know all items beforehand (if you have fetched all items into the memory) from your database table, then you could simply use `grid.setItems(yourItems)`
2. If you have a lot of items in your database you most likely want to implement lazy-loading. This means that data is retrieved from a backend, when needed.This is done using `DataProvider`interface There are a lot of examples of this also:

   - [Lazy loading with Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/blog/lazy-loading-with-vaadin-8)
   - [Data model providers](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers.html)
   - [ComboBox lazy loading with REST API in Vaadin 8](https://www.flowingcode.com/2018/04/combobox-lazy-loading-with-rest-api-in.html) This is not a Grid example, but an amazing example of DataProvider with data from REST. Exactly the same principles can be applied to a grid.
   - [Vaadin DataProvider Example](https://mindbug.in/vaadin/vaadin-dataprovider-example/)
   - [Java, Vaadin 8, lazy loading with grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633226/java-vaadin-8-lazy-loading-with-grid)

What is the exact problem you are facing with a display of data?